# type conversion exception

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

my Method is

```
 private void _fillText(string field, List<TextPart> parts, int alignment)    
 {
        //fieldPosition: page, llx, lly, urx, ury
        float[] fieldPosition = _pdfStamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(field);

        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = _pdfStamper.GetOverContent(fieldPosition[0]);

        foreach (TextPart tp in parts)

        {

            ColumnText myColumn = new ColumnText(pdfContentByte);

            myColumn.RunDirection = _runDirection;

            //if (_runDirection == PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL)

            //   tp.Font = _arialBlackFont12;

            myColumn.SetSimpleColumn(Convert.ToInt32(fieldPosition[1]) + tp.LeftMargin

                , fieldPosition[2]

                , fieldPosition[3] - tp.RightMargin

                , fieldPosition[4] - tp.TopMargin);

            Phrase myPhrase = new Phrase(new Chunk(tp.Text));

            //myPhrase.Font = font; 

            Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();

            myParagraph.Font = tp.Font;

            myParagraph.Font.SetStyle(tp.FontStyle);

            if (tp.Font == _lucidaSansGray60Font9)

                myParagraph.Leading = 10;

            if (tp.Leading != null)

                myParagraph.Leading = tp.Leading.Value;

            myParagraph.Alignment = alignment;

            myParagraph.Add(myPhrase);

            myColumn.AddElement(myParagraph);

            myColumn.Go();
        }
    }
```

At line

```
float[] fieldPosition = _pdfStamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(field);
```

I got error `cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.IList<Itextsharp.text.pdf.acrofields.fieldposition> to float array`

Somebody tell me how to convert. I have all my logic based on the conversion.

Comment: `float[] fieldPosition = _pdfStamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(field).Select(pos => // Do some logic to return a float).ToArray();`

Comment: @SepehrFarshid *`...Select(...)`* - unfortunately it is not quite this easy because each field position instance in the original list would have to be expanded to *five* floats.

Comment: ;) That's possible. But it would be better style IMO to make use of the better structured new `AcroFields.GetFieldPositions` type instead of going back to the less structured old type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to upgrade from some ancient iTextSharp version in which `AcroFields.GetFieldPositions` returned a list of 5 numbers per field visualization, page, llx, lly, urx, ury.

This meanwhile has been changed to a more structured design, you now get one FieldPosition instance which has an `int` page member and a `Rectangle` member.

You can of course convert this back to the old structure as proposed by Sepehr Farshid in his comments and attempted by LVBean in his new answer. For the sake of better source code quality, though, you might consider using the new `FieldPosition` object.

This would amount to something like (converted only in editor, minor errors might persist):

```
FieldPosition fieldPosition = _pdfStamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(field)[0];
PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = _pdfStamper.GetOverContent(fieldPosition.page);

foreach (TextPart tp in parts)
{
    ColumnText myColumn = new ColumnText(pdfContentByte);
    myColumn.RunDirection = _runDirection;

    myColumn.SetSimpleColumn(Convert.ToInt32(fieldPosition.position.Left) + tp.LeftMargin
            , fieldPosition.position.Bottom
            , fieldPosition.position.Right - tp.RightMargin
            , fieldPosition.position.Top - tp.TopMargin);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  float[] fieldPosition = _pdfStamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(field)
     .SelectMany(fp => new[] { fp.position.X, fp.position.Y, fp.position.Width, fp.position.Height })
     .ToList();
```

Comment: what will be the posrition of X and Y if i use this.??LVBen

Comment: @LVBen You forgot the initial page number. Each `fp` has to be expanded to a five-tuple `page, llx, lly, urx, ury`

Comment: @LVBen I tried this but did't work .can you give me the more better solution.